# DRY-ing up HTML with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dry

I have a number of Angular controllers that have the following chunk of code in them (including some more specific stuff that I can't factor out).

```
<h3>
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle pull-left" tooltip-html-unsafe="{{tooltip}}"></i>
  {{title}}
  <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin pull-right" ng-if="!dataLoaded"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-check fa-green pull-right" ng-if="dataLoaded && !dataError"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-exclamation fa-red pull-right" ng-if="dataError"></i>
</h3>
```

I'm looking to factor all of this out in the most Angular-ist way.  Would that be using a directive?  Also, will the all the controller-specific `{{tooltip}}` and `{{title}}` attributes still work, as well as the `ng-if`s, if I factor this code out?  Thanks--

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a directive you'll have to bind the scope with "=" and then things should work. The other way you can do this is to put that into an HTML file and bring it into the application in an `ng-include` like this:

```
<div ng-include="myfile.html">
</div>
```

If you do it with `ng-include` everything from your controller will bind into it just like normal.